# Loading theme assets in rails 6 jquery and assets load order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I have a rails app with the logic almost done and I'm now loading a theme from ThemeForest, I've loaded in the stylesheets, however, javascript wise I'm having issues. I've installed jquery via Yarn.

Here are the console errors

[image]

Here is my `application.js` file

[image]

As you can see it's linking the main.js file which is just a list of the themes javascript files as shown in the theme files

[image]

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create in app/assets/javascripts/main.js

In main.js file import your assets.. for example:

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
//= require fastclick/lib/fastclick
```

in your template

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'main', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```